# Manual testing on Mobile app tracking

Tags: analytics, mobile, tracking, application

My team is implementing analytics tracking on Mobile App. This app is available in mobile version only. Not a website app. 
I want to test the app in mobile devices if the tracking is working properly or not.

So in short i want a know the approach to emulate the mobile app in different mobiles. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks,
Priya

Comment: Sorry but the question is off-topic. You can emulate a mobile phone in most modern browsers i.e developer tools in both Chrome and Firefox. If you want proper mobile testing then you need to cough up money and pay for a paid service such as https://www.browserstack.com/responsive which offer a free trial.

Comment: Hi simon. Thank you for the response. I will try to edit the question and will not try asking the recommendation about tools. also my question is emulation of mobile apps. Not about mobile websites.

Comment: @SimonHayter I have edited the answers complying the rule. can you take this off hold. i would like to know the approaches people followed

Comment: Sorry but now after reviewing your question it is now off-topic because it is about Mobile APP Development and not about Webmastering a website. Your find information within the help centre what you can and can not ask on Pro Webmasters, for e.g in the first section `What topics can I ask about here? > This site is for anything that relates to owning, running, or administering your own website.` Stack Overflow may be more suitable for such development questions but read through their own rules before posting to avoid further disappointment.

Comment: Also your question requires a solution which will be in the form of a recommendation for a platform, your find many related questions like this already on Stack Overflow, e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525256/remote-test-laboratory-for-mobile-app-testing and many more on [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Mobile+app+testing+emulation&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=GoDCWJbrHa6LtgfS7ZHgCg). Please visit our help centre for further help and disappointment in the near future.